# How many AWS TextExtraction ConcurrentCall we can make

Tags: amazon-web-services, text-extraction

we have a scenario where multiple users want to hit for text Extraction tool provided by AWS. Do we have any limit, As per AWS document

"If you start too many jobs concurrently, calls to StartDocumentTextDetection raise a
LimitExceededException exception (HTTP status code: 400) until the number of concurrently
running jobs is below the Amazon Textract service limit."

Answer (score 0):

I have used AWS Textract in the past and I didn't have any problem like yours.

You can send an email to AWS Support to increase your limit.